# $FILES array is not multiple

Tags: php, arrays

I have this field:

```
<input name="thumbnail" type="file" id="fileElem" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
```

Why when I var_dump `$_FILES['thumbnail']` i have only one image in array:

```
array(5) { ["name"]=> string(14) "2020-03-23.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(34) "/usr/multiphp/php7.3/tmp/phpX5uyG2" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(620367) }
```

Please help me with this

Comment: how many images did you upload? Is there anything in the rest of $_FILES?

Comment: I uploaded 3 images

Comment: In $_FILES is only one element of thumbnail

Comment: You must write `<input name="thumbnail[]"` in the HTML I think. See the marked duplicate, in the blue box above, for more details.

Comment: I try to use thumbnail[] but it still doesn't work

Comment: Study the rest of the examples then and ensure there is nothing else you have missed.